# Addin adtional jQuery code into MVC 5 project won't load the new code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this simple code in a js script into an MVC5 project.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    });
```

I try to add code but the new code does not load into the browser, is there some cache involved or how come the browser remembers only the old file.
Need to mention that I cleard all cookies, cache from browser, clean, build and rebuild the solution in VS, but I think somewhere else is the problem...

View using JS and CSS

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ProgramareMF</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataProgramare, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataProgramare, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder="Alege Data Programare", @id = "datepicker" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataProgramare, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
        <div class="example">
            <select data-bind="options: hourOptions, optionsText: formatTimeOption, value: startDateHour"></select>
            <select data-bind="options: minuteOptions, optionsText: formatTimeOption, value: startDateMinute"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PacientNume, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PacientNume, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Nume" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PacientNume, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PacientEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PacientEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PacientEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, no still nothing...

Comment: did that now, but did it in the past with no effect, I see now that I had an open session of the project on firefox, now using chrome, closing that loaded the added jQuery.. thansk for your reply

Comment: Why do you have a ready handler inside a ready handler? `$(document).ready()` and `$(function(){})` are functionally the same.

Comment: I have more code added, so I put datepicker in $(function(){}) for better readability I think

Comment: It's strange, now I'm adding some css code and it doesn't load to the browser... So in Visual Studio the changes are saved but in the browser the new code is not added

Comment: @AndreiMaieras There is no way to explain that behavior based purely on what you've shown here. How are you referencing the CSS file? How are you viewing the site? Have you tried a hard refresh (the Ctrl+F5 keyboard command that Ofiris first mentioned)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that hard refresh, no change, every time I tried to add some code into css or js files won't show in the browser. I just simply add code into css and/or js files, save, build and run in chrome. I see now that a cookie romoval is needed.. but with this change too, sometimes works sometimes  needs more refreshes

Comment: can you post the code of the view where the js and css files are loaded?

Comment: I added the view in my question

Comment: I never quick test in Chrome because it caches a ton of things for a long time. Things like script files, css, and even authentication sometimes. I use IE to test because it is the lowest common denominator among browsers. I set it to delete everything each time it exits so then each time I restart a debugging session the browser goes out and gets all the new files. This makes it much easier to see your changes, especially in script files and css. And IE integrates into Visual Studio better IMO.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I guess I need to get used to IE , so I'll do my development , then test and return with an anwser, thanks :)

Comment: So that was the problem,checking that IE deletes temporary files, history, cookies, saved passwords and web form information on exit does the trick, now everytime I change some js or css is seen in the browser.